# Create data frame from xml in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

New to R... I am having trouble creating a data frame from an xml file in R. Looking for some help. My code is below. After creating data frame from this particular xml file, I need to add multiple other (similarly formatted) xml files to the same data frame. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

And the code:

```
library(XML)     # ONLY PACKAGE NEEDED

# library(plyr)


urls <- c("https:_file_.xml")


data <- (read_xml(urls))


df_list <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
  penalty_reports <- xmlParse(data)
  df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(penalty_reports, "//Result"))
})


penalties_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

# final_df <- plyr::rbind.fill(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is fairly flat and hence consider using XML's `xmlToDataFrame()`. And to combine multiple files, build a list of dataframes with `lapply`, parsing from a list of URLs. Then, row bind all dataframe elements with `do.call(rbind, ...)` which assumes all fields are the same. If not use plyr's [`rbind.fill`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rbind.fill).

```
library(XML)    # ONLY PACKAGE NEEDED
# library(plyr)

urls <- c("https://_file1_.xml", "https://_file2_.xml", "https://_file3_.xml")

df_list <- lapply(urls, function(url) {
   penalty_report <- xmlParse(readLines(url))
   df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(penalty_report, "//Result"))
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
# final_df <- plyr::rbind.fill(df_list)
```

Comment: My answer does not use `read_xml`. Do you need to read XMLs from URL or filesystem?

Comment: I edited the code in my question above to show you what I have working. Without 'read_xml' I get a 'does not appear to be XML' error. I have a single file in a nice looking data frame now. I can't get the list of urls to work because the 'read_xml' function isn't working with multiple files. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What package is `read_xml` from? Your code is not compilable without the listed library.  See edit wrapping URL content in `readLines()`. Do not mix libraries as `read_xml` may not be interchangeable with `xmlParse`.